# How to play pre-roll, mid-roll and post-roll ads using jwplayer android sdk

Tags: java, android, jwplayer

I am new in JWPlayer. I got a licence from jwplayer and working on it. I dont know how to play ads in mid-roll, pre-roll and post-roll. Also I tried but cant find any good resource. Please guide me. My trial period will expire soon. Thanks in advance. I have tried the following code. I really have no idea how to play ads on JWPlayer.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements VideoPlayerEvents.OnFullscreenListener
    {
        JWPlayerView mPlayerView;
        private JWEventHandler mEventHandler;
        String videoUri;
        ArrayList<AdBreak> adsBreakList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
            mPlayerView = (JWPlayerView)findViewById(R.id.jwplayer);
            videoUri = "http:"+getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
            adsBreakList = new ArrayList<>();
            mPlayerView.addOnFullscreenListener(this);
            mEventHandler = new JWEventHandler(mPlayerView);

            Ad ad1 = new Ad(AdSource.VAST, videoUri);
            AdBreak ad = new AdBreak("pre", ad1);
            adsBreakList.add(ad);

            PlaylistItem pi = new PlaylistItem.Builder().file(videoUri).adSchedule(adsBreakList).build();
            mPlayerView.load(pi);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question, please provide code of what you have tried so far and what is not working. Keep in mind a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article on playing VAST Ads, VMAPs, and loading both into Google IMA for JW Player: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/interaction/advertising/

Additionally, you may want to check out the advertising classes in the API reference: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/reference/

Hopefully these articles help, if not, please feel free to comment again here or open up a support case with JW Player to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks @Josie Keller, I liked your response. Its helpful. But sorry I don't have idea how to create xml for ads. We have to purchase my own ads server or anything else. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: @FarhanAli, you will generate your ad tags on DoubleClick for Publishers (https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1131465?hl=en).  Or if you prefer getting up and running right away, check out the DFP sample tags over here (https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/tags) to test your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Live video streaming with pre roll, midroll ads using JW Player**

```
 public class LiveTv extends BaseActivity implements      VideoPlayerEvents.OnErrorListener{

String path = "your video stream path";
String preRoll = "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net or any other ad url";
String midRoll = "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net or any other ad url";
ArrayList<PlaylistItem> videosList = new ArrayList<PlaylistItem>();
private Ad ad;
private AdBreak adBreak;
private LinkedList<AdBreak> schedule;
private PlaylistItem playItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.livetv);
    JWPlayerFragment fragment = (JWPlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.playerFragment);
    // Get a handle to the JWPlayerView
    JWPlayerView playerView = fragment.getPlayer();
    playerView.playAd(preRoll);

    ad = new Ad(AdSource.VAST, midRoll);
    adBreak = new AdBreak("10%", ad);
    schedule = new LinkedList<>();
    schedule.add(adBreak);
    playItem = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
            .file(path)
            .adSchedule(schedule) // Set the Ad Schedule
            .build();

    playerView.addOnAdErrorListener(new AdvertisingEvents.OnAdErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdError(String s, String s1) {
            Log.d("adLoaad","adload failed");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error loading ad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    playerView.load(playItem);
}

@Override
public void onError(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JW player Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
 }
```